# how hide address bar in mobile using javascript or css

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

we want to know how we can to hide address bar of mobile browser.
we see few topics about of this problem and we test them and don't working.
please check your code is hide address bar and help me to know how we should to do

```
we want to hide mobile browser address bar (URL bar) with using javascript or css.
```

[image]

thanks everyone for help

Comment: Please provide all relevant code in a code snippet.

Comment: i dont have any code and i dont know how i should hide address bar i need help to know it

Answer (score 1):

What code have you tried previously?

This is a pretty standard way of hiding the address bar in mobile.

```
// New event listener:
window.addEventListener("load",function() {
    setTimeout(function(){
        // Hide the address bar:
        window.scrollTo(0, 1);
    }, 0);
});
```

JSFiddle to demonstrate: https://jsfiddle.net/bjcra2vx/

Comment: As far as I can tell this no longer works

Answer (score 0):

Extended solution from above. This should cover all bases for you. Next time please share your own attempts first:

```
// Extended solution for hiding address bar:

(function() {
    
  var browser = window,
      doc = browser.document;

  // If there's a hash, or addEventListener is undefined, stop here
  if ( !location.hash || !browser.addEventListener ) {

    //set to 1
    window.scrollTo( 0, 1 );
    var scrollTop = 1,

    //reset to 0 if needed
    checkWindowBody = setInterval(function(){
      if( doc.body ){
        clearInterval( checkWindowBody );
        scrollTop = "scrollTop" in doc.body ? doc.body.scrollTop : 1;
        browser.scrollTo( 0, scrollTop === 1 ? 0 : 1 );
      } 
    }, 15 );

    if (browser.addEventListener) {
      browser.addEventListener("load", function(){
        setTimeout(function(){
          //reset to hide address
          browser.scrollTo( 0, scrollTop === 1 ? 0 : 1 );
        }, 0);
      }, false );
    }
  }

})();
```

Comment: Struggling with the same issue for weeks now. A third party chat component (needs scrolling) running full screen on a page that does not need any scrolling. Is you solution also for that usecase?