# How to make address bar disappear on mobile, using Mat-Toolbar?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

I am building a site and using Angular.
I have a toolbar, create with Mat-Toolbar, from Angular Material.
When I enter the site from my mobile, small part of my site bottom is not visible.
When I scroll down on mobile device, then scroll up and down again, the address bar is disappeared, and I can see 100% of my site.

How can I force that scrolling, or make the address bar disappear in Mobile devices?

I have tried using window.scrollTo, and it makes the site scroll down, but the address bar still there - so it doesn't help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how hide address bar in mobile using javascript or css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70415416/how-hide-address-bar-in-mobile-using-javascript-or-css)

Comment: I have tried this, but it didnt helped. Site is really scrolling down, but address bar still there.

Comment: you can use the flex package and then hide your address bar just by doing fxhide.sm something like this... if need any help in this... provide stackblitz with the issue... will work on it

Comment: Please put your code in a stackblitz. I'd be happy to take a look